# Apache Pig escape column name

Tags: apache-pig

I am reading `Parquet` logs in `PIG`. Log schema contains a field `FULL` nested under field `USER`. Since `FULL` is a keyword in Pig I can't load the file. Pig is giving compile time errors. There is no way to escape such field name. It would really adverse to change column name in schema. This is what I am using to load

```
user_parquet = LOAD 'test' USING org.apache.parquet.pig.ParquetLoader();
user_normalized = FOREACH user_parquet GENERATE ..... USER.FULL as user_full ...
```

I tried escaping with ``` \, ``, '' ``` but none of them worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I solved the issue by referring  field with field number instead of field name:-

```
user_parquet = LOAD 'test' USING org.apache.parquet.pig.ParquetLoader();
user_normalized = FOREACH user_parquet GENERATE ..... USER.$0 as user_full ...
```

Pig, as any other language as no way to escape keyword if used as variable name.

Comment: variable or keyword?https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Keywords

Comment: I meant a variable name which happens to be a keyword. 'full' in my case